# Remove null or empty strings for mapped fields in DynamoDB

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
//Data Model

[DynamoDBTable("ContactsTable")]
public class Contact
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey(AttributeName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "Address1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "Address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}

    public void SaveContactsToDynamoDb()
    {
        var config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
        config.ServiceURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"];

        var context = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(config));

        var contactBatchWrite = context.CreateBatchWrite<Contact>();

        var contacts = GetContacts();

        contactBatchWrite.AddPutItems(contacts.Select(contact => new Contact
        {
            Id = contact.Id.ToString(),
            FirstName = contact.FirstName,
            LastName = contact.LastName,
            Address1 = contact.Address1,
            Address2 = contact.Address2
        }));

        contactBatchWrite.Execute();
    }
```

When I execute it it returns an exception saying that "AttributeValue may not contain an empty string". I understand that some of the fields for a particular contact that are being mapped might contain empty fields. As DynamoDB does not accept null or empty fields, is there any way that I can modify the data model to add some attribute to property which ignores if its null or empty? Or can anyone give me a better way to map/ handle in this situation. I do not want to add constant like "N/A" if null or empty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DynamoDB does accept `null` as attribute value when mapping Objects. It just drops the attribute internally.

If you need 2 empty values (null and empty string) you will have to use an __EMPTY_STRING constant, otherwise - you can just use `null`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one another question, do you think you can provide me your suggestion on it - Its on querying the DynamoDB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329008/get-the-max-date-get-the-last-added-item-in-dynamodb

Comment: @chen-harel do you know if there is a way to do this handling through boto3? so on a put_item() operation, if there are any attributes which are '' it will handle it accordingly. I'm asking because my use case is such that we don't know our attributes beforehand...