# Get the Max Date / Get the last added item in DynamoDB

Tags: c#-4.0, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Hi This is my table schema

Contacts table:

```
"KeySchema": [{
    "AttributeName": "DateTimeRetrieved",
    "KeyType": "HASH"
},{
    "AttributeName": "Id",
    "KeyType": "RANGE"
}]
```

My primary key has DateTimeRetrieved as the primary key. I would like to retrieve the latest datetime that was entered into the table. It is also equal to the last added items datetime.

Is there a way to query this? . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not recommended:** If your table is small you can always `Select` all the data and order it in the application level.

It is a bit abusive to try and find order in hash keys. Ordering is done on range and secondary indices. To use DynamoDB efficiently you should model the data as "buckets" (hash keys) and ask questions using `Query` on the 2nd level.

Without knowing what you're actually modeling it is hard to help but a good read is the [Local Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) that allows you to have query even on an attribute.
With range / LSI you can give order to rows and query the "last" one.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I am writing a batch process which queries external db and saves the items according in DynamoDB. I had to create the pimarykey as LastDateTimeRetrieved because for every certain number of hours the batch process runs and saves the entire contents across a datetimehash key. The next time the batch process runs It should get the last saved datetime / Max datetime from Dynamodb to query against external dbs. I think saving just the lastdatetime in a seperate table everytime I put items into dynamodb  might be the best choice.. ??

Comment: yes, I believe keeping it elsewhere and not trying to compute it using a dynamodb api call is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the date in the range, in order to perform Query with "startsWith" parameter.

For example:

Key: Date in YYYY-MM
Range Key: Date in DD + Id

So, you can issue queries like "give me all the items for 2013-12 for the days starting with "0" (that would give you all the items from the 01 til -09 of December 2013).

Then at the application level, you can parse the ID